# How do I troubleshoot sites not served only by specific ISP

Tags: nginx

I am hosting two websites on a Linode server. One site is static `HTML` and the other one uses `Wagtail` which is built on the `Django` framework. I use `nginx`. Now, the sites are working properly but recently I realised that this is not true for everyone. The issue seems to be related to their specific ISP and it causes people to see this message:

[image: error message]

Even when I click at this point the site will not be served.

This seems to be an issue with the ISP but it is still the case that the people that have the issue with my site have no issues with the rest of the web so there much be something I can change to fix it. Would be grateful for any pointers on how to troubleshoot this!

————————————————

Here is my `nginx` configuration for the `Wagtail/Django` website:

```
server {
  server_name www.gagatsis.com;
  return 301 $scheme://gagatsis.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  server_name gagatsis.com;
  root /srv/www/gagatsis.com/code/;

  access_log /srv/www/gagatsis.com/code/logs/access.log;
  error_log /srv/www/gagatsis.com/code/logs/error.log;

  location /static/ {
    root /srv/www/gagatsis.com/code/;
  }

  location /media/ {
    root /srv/www/gagatsis.com/code/;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
  }

}
```

and for the other one:

```
server {
  server_name www.xathin.com;
  return 301 $scheme://xathin.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name xathin.com;
  root /srv/www/xathin.com;
  index index.htm index.html;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps they're trying to use HTTPS ?

Answer (score 2):

You server has both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, but your nginx config listens only to IPv4.

```
$ host gagatsis.com
gagatsis.com has address 139.162.253.225
gagatsis.com has IPv6 address 2a01:7e00::f03c:91ff:fe2c:cf3f
gagatsis.com mail is handled by 10 mail.gagatsis.com.

$ curl -s -6 gagatsis.com | grep h1
    <h1>Welcome to the server!</h1>

$ curl -s -4 gagatsis.com | grep h1
                <h1>Alexander Gagatsis</h1>
```

Fix it by adding this line `listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;` to all server blocks.

Comment: Thank you for checking! You have a typo. It is `ipv6only`. This was not the solution but trying it out led me to the issue which seemed to have been a spurious `default` file on my `sites-enabled` folder. Thanks! 

Comment: I think this was the solution. Nice catch, Alexey!